# Can one export a Power BI visual to its JS source code?

Tags: powerbi

I need to export a standard Power BI visual in order to use it as a template for a customized visual, then import it back to Power BI. I am using a web-based Power BI and my operating system is Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the power bi standard visuals are open source, so you can use them as a base for your design. You’ll not be able to access them via the web version, you also need to use the desktop program to test them/add them to the report.

https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2016/02/10/open-source-power-bi-visuals/

If you got to the Microsoft GitHub and filter on the list of repo's you will see a list of items and tools for Power BI Visual creation

https://github.com/orgs/microsoft/repositories?q=power-bi&type=all&language=&sort=